# pandas get column average for rows with a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I can't get the average of values of a column in pandas based on the values of a different column. For example

```
>>> df
         ID     city     timeDiff
0        1       A       2
1        2       A       3
2        3       A       4     
3        4       B       6
3        5       B       6
```

What I am trying to get is avg of timeDiff for specific cities
like

A : (2+3+4)/3 = 3

B : (6+6)/2 = 6

I understand I can get column specific average via df[columnName].mean() but I am not sure how to first group on city name and then find the average ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
df.groupby("city")["timeDiff"].mean()
```

Comment: great question and a great aanswer

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5], 'city': ['A','A','A','B','B'],'timeDiff':[2,3,4,6,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
mean_df = df.groupby(['city'])['timeDiff'].mean()
```

Comment: The `mean()` you link to in docs is different from the `mean()` you actually use in your answer. The parameters in the docs will not work here. For example you cannot pass in a `skipna`